# Mule 4 : 'Using Keyword' : How to add condition for creating the local variable in Mule DataWeave 2.0 - 'using' function

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I want to create a local variable under **`using`** function

```
dataweave 1.0
result : using (myVar = 1 when $.age > 1 otherwise 2) {
}
```

The above code works!

Same logic I want to achieve in `dataweave 2.0` something like below (Below code does not work)

```
dataweave 2.0
result : using (
            if ($.age > 1) 
               myVar = 1
            else 
               myVar  = 2
         ) {
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of `do` scope and declare variables as it's more of a recommended [approach](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-variables#example_local_variable).

With **do**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
result : do {
      var myVar = if (payload.age > 1) 1 else 2
      ---
      myVar
}
```

With **using**.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    result: using (myVar = if (payload.age > 1) 1 else 2) 
         myVar
}
```